# Clock Box Animation with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, clock

I want to create an animation like showed in this [video](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ab7c70e4a2edb84871db67914abc93fe20221101111438/08a42b).

I already created a view that shows the current time, splitted in three boxes, but I dont know how to animate it. Thank you for your help!

This is my enviroment object, which gets the current time:

```
import SwiftUI


class TimeManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var date = Date()
    @Published var oldDate = Date()

    func timeString(timeFormat: String, date: Date) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = timeFormat
        
        let time = formatter.string(from: date)
        return time
    }
    
    // update time
    var updateTimer: Timer {
        withAnimation(.spring()){
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true,
                                 block: {_ in
                
                self.oldDate = self.date
                self.date = Date()
                
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the view, which splits the time in boxes:

```
struct BoxesView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var timeManager: TimeManager
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 30) {
            
            let timeElements = splitUpTime()
            
            ForEach(timeElements, id: \.self) { timeElement in
                SingleBoxElement(text: timeElement)
            }
            
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    
    func splitUpTime() -> Array<String> {
        
        let splitDate = timeManager.timeString(timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss", date: timeManager.date).components(separatedBy: ":")
        
        return splitDate
    }
}

struct SingleBox: View {
    
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
            
            ZStack {
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .foregroundColor(.pink)
                
                Text(text)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .monospacedDigit()
                
                
            }.frame(width: 90, height: 90)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have forgotten to add the video

Comment: I added my video, thank you for the reminder. Is ist common to use WeTransfer or do you prefer other services?

Comment: Questions should be self contained and should not rely on outside resources, that way if the outside resource disappears then the question is still valuable to those that may be looking for a similar answer.

Comment: @MultiMedia - instead of saying *"go download this video to see what I want to do"*, take a moment to think it through and ***describe*** your goal. For example: *"I have a Text object. When I change the string, I want the current string to slide down and out the bottom while the new string slides in from the top."* Including an image (that you can whip up in a minute or two) can help. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBm5i.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example --

On each tap of the "Next" button, it increments the value... sliding the "old" string down-and-out the bottom and the "new" string down-and-in from the top:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextTransition: View {
    @State private var secondsValue = "21"
    @State private var seconds: Int = 21

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 50) {
            ZStack {
                Text(secondsValue)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .monospacedDigit()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 40)
                    .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .top), removal: .move(edge: .bottom)))
                    .id("Seconds" + secondsValue)
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 60, height: 40)
            .clipped()
            
            Button("Next") {
                seconds += 1
                withAnimation (.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    self.secondsValue = "\(seconds)"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now all you need to do is implement your `TimeManager` to update `secondsValue` (and minutes and hours values for their Text elements).